# Return Javascript Variables from jQuery AJAX call overwriting previous Javascript/JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

thanks for reading.  I have a conundrum that I just can seem to lick.  I created a jQuery plugin that creates table rows based off a JSON object.  In this plugin I wish to have pagination that has an AJAX call which results in a new JSON object with the same variable name with different key/value pairs (I want to overwrite it).  On success I can alert the data but cannot access the variables in the data that I am alerting.

```
var grid = { 
    "name": "test", 
    "columns":
    [
        {"name":"col1"},
        {"name":"col2"}
    ], 
    "rows":
    [
         {"name":"col1", "value":"text1"},
         {"name":"col2", "value":"text2"}
    ] 
}
$("#myDiv").makeTable(); <-- plugin that creates table based off this JSON
// if I alert grid.columns[0].name I get col1 no problem.
```

Then I do some jQuery stuff to loop through and create a table, no problem...

then I have this block of code from within my makeTable() plugin:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'get_json-pages.php',
type: "GET",
data: form_data, <-- my string
dataType:"script", <-- set it to script because the output is just the javascript
success: function(data) {
            alert(data); <-- alerts perfectly, looks like the same JSON above but 
            with different key/value pairs
            the alert looks like this:
            var grid = { 
                 "name": "test", 
                 "columns":
                 [
                     {"name":"col3"},
                     {"name":"col4"}
                 ], 
                 "rows":
                 [
                     {"name":"col3", "value":"text3"},
                     {"name":"col4", "value":"text4"}
                 ]  
             }

           now when I do this:
           alert(grid.columns[0].name);
           it is a blank alert?
}
});
```

How can I overwrite a JSON object with the AJAX JSON and Reload my plugin in order to show the new set of data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to leave commentary inside your code can you use actual comments `//` so we can see what you're really running. If that code actually runs (as you say it does with the first alert), and you next declare a variable called `grid` then your next alert will work [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GfCKW/). However, I suspect that you are actually trying to access properties of `data` which is a string, not an object, since you specified `dataType:"script"`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a plugin access anything outside of itself that the user doesn't pass in. If you want your "plugin" to accept an object, then you should pass a reference to the plugin.

```
$("#myDiv").makeTable({data:grid});
```

For pagination you could take one of two approaches. The simple answer would be to re-run your plugin with each pagination call.

```
$.ajax({
success: function(data) {    
    var grid //construct new object from data 
    $("#myDiv").makeTable({data:grid});
}
});
```

Or you can have your plugin accept a "data source". Depending on what you mean by an ajax source this can be trivial (go get all the data at once), or tricky (alter your requests to get only get each "page" of data at a time).

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I have a few reasons why I am doing what I am doing. Its a local app, not public.  I tried your concept and it did not work at all.  Does anyone know a better way to rewrite a global JSON object? Oh, and thanks to who ever thought I didn't put in enough research effort for this... Booooo...

Comment: I think if you want any help on this one you're going to have to post some more complete code. All we can offer without actual code is stylistic advice which I think you're going to have challenges implementing.